# User with the highest amount per month for the last 12 months mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `like` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `like` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `userid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `dateline` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `to_userid` int(10) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I would like to have a list for the last twelve months, showing the to_userid with the highest sum of like, next to the month and year.

edit:  dateline is stored as unix time.

Can anyone help with this please?

Comment: We can't help you fix your query if you don't show it. And we're not going to do all your work for you.

Comment: @Barmar Oh, it seems like we are :-(

Comment: @BrianTyndall - you'll need to solve the [groupwise maximum issue in MySql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql)

Comment: Thanks, that is a useful pointer to work from. I wasn't expecting the query to be written for me :)